# How does CLR recognizes manage code?

Tags: .net

How does CLR recognizes managed code from unmanaged code?

Thanks

SNA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are flags in the [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) that indicate managed code.

> Microsoft's .NET Framework has
>   extended the PE format with features
>   which support the Common Language
>   Runtime. Among the additions are a CLR
>   Header and CLR Data section. Upon
>   loading a binary, the OS loader yields
>   execution to the CLR via a reference
>   in the PE/COFF IMPORT table. The CLR
>   then loads the CLR Header and Data
>   sections.